Step 3/7 : COPY package*.json ./ COPY failed: no source files were specified
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.594MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:16
16: Pulling from library/node
311da6c465ea: Pull complete
7e9bf114588c: Pull complete
ffd9397e94b7: Pull complete
513d77925604: Pull complete
ae3b95bbaa61: Pull complete
0e421f66aff4: Pull complete
ca266fd61921: Pull complete
ee7d78be1eb9: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f77a1aef2da8d83e45ec990f45df50f1a286c5fe8bbfb8c6e4246c6389705c0b
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:16
 ---> 1ddc7e4055fd
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in a6e1bd23c8bc
Removing intermediate container a6e1bd23c8bc
 ---> 430e5d0cecf7
Step 3/7 : COPY package*.json ./
COPY failed: no source files were specified

my docker file
# Use an official Node runtime as a parent image
FROM node:16

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Make port 3000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 3000

# Define the command to run the application
CMD ["node", "app.js"]


In the current directory (where you run the command) you do not have file(s) package*.json

Please edit your question to add context, and choose a title that describes the problem rather than pasting in an error message
